# sql statement in a bash script "command not found"

Tags: mysql, bash

I've got a bash script that runs a series of sql statements:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -u root -p << QUERY_INPUT

CREATE DATABASE dba_first;
CREATE DATABASE dba_second;
CREATE DATABASE dba_third;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `dba%`.* TO `dbuser`@`localhost`;

QUERY_INPUT
```

When I run the script, I get: `./quick.sh: line 20: dba%: command not found`

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What is on line 20?

Comment: It was the `\`dba%\`` backticks not being escaped properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by a nice person on IRC; have to escape the `

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \`dba%\`.* TO \`dbuser\`@\`localhost\`;
```